# How to solve "could not find driver" error in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I am getting database connection error in laravel. I am requesting to check my code.

I already tried to remove semicolon(;) in php.ini file

route.php:

```
Route::get('/Insert', 'UserController@insert');
```

UserController.php:

```
public function insert(Request $request)
{
    $result=DB::insert("insert into test (id, name, email) values(?,?,?)",['1','Nirav','n@gmail.com']);

    $result=DB::select("select * from test");
    print_r($result);
}
```

database.php:

```
DATABASE NAME  :  data
TABLE NAME     :  test

'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

'mysql' => [
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', "data"),
    'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', "root"),
    'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ""),
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
    'strict'    => true,
],
```

.env file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=data
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

I am inserting record in database.

Comment: which laravel version you using right now

Comment: If you run `php -m` does it show pdo_mysql in the list of modules?

Comment: Yes It shows PDO module (instead of pdo_mysql). @Ryan J Field

Comment: Laravel version 5.1 @romil

Comment: Route::post('/Insert', 'UserController@insert');

Comment: No If i use post method it shows me error "MethodNotAllowedHttpException". @romil

Comment: are you using ubuntoo/linux

Comment: sudo apt-get -y install php5-mysql  ........try this

Comment: No i am using windows. @romil

Comment: @Nirav check my answer

Answer (score 0):

you need install PDO_MYSQL driver for your PHP

Answer (score 0):

- Go to `wamp64/www/bin/php/php*` (where * is the php version you are using)
- Edit file php and uncomment this line by removing the semicolon:

`;extension=pdo_pgsql to extension=pdo_pgsql`

Save and restart your Wamp/xampp server

check your `.env` and `config/database` again.

Comment: which php version you are using

Comment: Laravel version 5.1

Comment: PHP version 7.2.18

Comment: i think you should use php 5 ,7.0, 7.1

Answer (score 0):

```
If you are on windows, and your php folder is not in your PATH, you have set the absolute directory in your php.ini

for example:

extension_dir = "C:/php7/ext"
and uncomment

extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
Restart apache2.4 and it should work.

I hope it helps.
```